# Push a new UIViewController when I click in a cell in a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I need to open a `ViewController` when I click in a `UIPopoverController` cell.
`SeccionesViewController` is the `ViewController` that I put in the `UIPopoverController`, that is a table. The function that not works is `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from `TableView`.

Thank you for advance.

My code to show `UIPopoverController` is:

```
-(IBAction)seccionesButtonTapped:(id)sender
{

        if (_itemPicker == nil) {
            //Create the ColorPickerViewController.
            _itemPicker = [[SeccionesViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

            //Set this VC as the delegate.
            _itemPicker.delegate = self;
        }

        if (_itemPickerPopover == nil) {
            //The color picker popover is not showing. Show it.
            _itemPickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_itemPicker];
            //[_itemPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
            [_itemPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(350, 902, 300, 300) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
        } else {
            //The color picker popover is showing. Hide it.
            [_itemPickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }
}
```

The `SeccionesViewController` code is:

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    if ([super initWithStyle:style] != nil) {

        //Initialize the array
        _itemNames = [NSMutableArray array];

        //Set up the array of colors.
        [_itemNames addObject:AMLocalizedString(@"listaTareas", @"")];
        [_itemNames addObject:AMLocalizedString(@"EventosTab", @"")];

        //Make row selections persist.
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        //Calculate how tall the view should be by multiplying the individual row height
        //by the total number of rows.
        NSInteger rowsCount = [_itemNames count];
        NSInteger singleRowHeight = [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        NSInteger totalRowsHeight = rowsCount * singleRowHeight;

        //Calculate how wide the view should be by finding how wide each string is expected to be
        CGFloat largestLabelWidth = 0;
        for (NSString *itemName in _itemNames) {
            //Checks size of text using the default font for UITableViewCell's textLabel. 
            CGSize labelSize = [itemName sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]];
            if (labelSize.width > largestLabelWidth) {
                largestLabelWidth = labelSize.width;
            }
        }

        //Add a little padding to the width
        CGFloat popoverWidth = largestLabelWidth + 100;

        //Set the property to tell the popover container how big this view will be.
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(popoverWidth, totalRowsHeight);
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_itemNames count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [_itemNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selectedItem = [_itemNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSUserDefaults *dispositivo = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *dis = [dispositivo stringForKey:@"dispositivo"];

    if ([selectedItem isEqualToString:AMLocalizedString(@"listaTareas", @"")]) {

        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:dis bundle:nil];
        ListaTareasViewController *tareas= [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListaTareasView"];
        tareas.communitykey = communitykey;
        tareas.tituloAsig = tituloAsig;
        tareas.infoH = infoH;
        if ((vengoDe != 1) && (vengoDe != 2) && (vengoDe != 3)) {
            tareas.vengoDe = 1;
        }else{
            tareas.vengoDe = vengoDe;
        }
        tareas.infoAsig = infoAsig;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tareas animated:YES];

    }else if ([selectedItem isEqualToString:AMLocalizedString(@"EventosTab", @"")]){

        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:dis bundle:nil];
        ListaEventosViewController *eventos= [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"listaEventosView"];
        eventos.communitykey = communitykey;
        eventos.nomAsig = tituloAsig;
        eventos.infoH = infoH;
        if ((vengoDe != 1) && (vengoDe != 2) && (vengoDe != 3)) {
            eventos.vengoDe = 1;
        }else{
            eventos.vengoDe = vengoDe;
        }
        eventos.infoAsig = infoAsig;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventos animated:YES];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code:

```
        //Set this VC as the delegate.
        _itemPicker.delegate = self;
```

which makes it look like you're on the right track. But then you reload the storyboard, instantiate a controller and push it into a navigation controller that doesn't exist (so, no crash, but no result either).

When you should be doing is using that delegate relationship to pass the `selectedItem` back to the source view controller. Once there, that view controller does have access to the navigation controller so it can decide how to use the `selectedItem` to create a controller and push that controller for display.

It is possible that you could pass `tareas` / `eventos` back to the delegate instead of `selectedItem`. Who should own the knowledge of which view controller is required and how it should be configured is something for you to decide based on your app structure.

Comment: Something like this: `self.navigationController.delegate = self;` ??

Comment: No. Passing back to the delegate would be like `[self.delegate seccionesViewController:self didSelectItem:##XXX##];` where ##XXX## is the view controller or the selected item.

Comment: In `SeccionesViewController`, what are you currently using `self.delegate` for?

Comment: I think I need this:     `//Notify the delegate if it exists.
    if (_delegate != nil) {
        [_delegate selectedCell:0];
    }`

Comment: Something like that yes, though `selectedCell:` is a poor method signature (who is the call coming from, what for) - look at the `UITableView` delegate methods for inspiration of good method signatures.